# How to use IMPORTXML to import hidden div tag?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data from https://bando.tphcm.gov.vn/ogis
I can't import a hidden div tag.

[image: Elements in the web developer tools]

I want import all data to Google Sheets.

[image: Redenered element of interest]

Comment: It is impossible to access the site! I would like to know if it contains a jason for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Content from this website is loaded dynamically via script, which makes it unreachable via formulas like [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).

You can check that by [disabling JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/) and refreshing the page: you'll get the following message:

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

The content doesn't seem to be accessible via [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) either.

#### Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun)